# What exactly does it stand for `ClassName.(params: params)` in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

I've seen this syntax:

`ClassName.(params: params)` but I don't get what exactly it does under the hood. Is it an alternative to `.call` or `.new`?

Comment: `anything.(arguments)` is shorthand for `anything.call(arguments)`. That being said you would need to be much more specific as to what `ClassName` is as the idiom you are describing is not common in a rails core code base.

Comment: It's an interactor so makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Although it's a language feature, it's only documented under [`Proc#call`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Proc.html#method-i-call): _"Note that `prc.()` invokes `prc.call()` with the parameters given. It’s syntactic sugar to hide “call”."_